# unmarshal json field is int or string

Tags: go

I have an app where the type is

```
type Person struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Age  int    `json:"age"`
}
```

But we have legacy clients that send the `Age` field as either a string or an integer, so...

```
{
  "name": "Joe",
  "age": "42"
}
```

OR

```
{
  "name": "Joe",
  "age": 42
}
```

I know I can annotate the "age" field with ",string" if it's a string that I want coerced into an integer, but what if the field could be either one?

Comment: If you can use `json.Number` https://play.golang.com/p/J1wtELaHEI7

Comment: If you can't, or don't want to, change the type of the struct field, you can do something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/attt6yLBzt8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

func (p *Person) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var objMap map[string]*json.RawMessage
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &objMap)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var name string
    err = json.Unmarshal(*objMap["name"], &name)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var ageInt int
    err = json.Unmarshal(*objMap["age"], &ageInt)
    if err != nil {
        // age  is string
        var ageString string
        err = json.Unmarshal(*objMap["age"], &ageString)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        aI, err := strconv.Atoi(ageString)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        p.Age = aI

    } else {
        p.Age = ageInt
    }

    p.Name = name

    fmt.Printf("%+v", *p)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    p := `{"name": "John", "age": "10"}`
    //  p := `{"name": "John", "age": 10}`


    newP := Person{}
    err := newP.UnmarshalJSON([]byte(p))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error %+v", err)
    }

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/AK8H_wdNqmt

You can try something like this. Try to read and parse Into int, if that fails check for string value, parse it to int and then assign int value to person struct

Answer (score 5):

Check out ["json - raw Message"](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) in the docs, from there on out you can try to parse it however you want. Example below and on [GoPlayground](https://play.golang.org/p/f-wJWjcDVxv)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string          `json:"name"`
    Age  json.RawMessage `json:"age"`
}

func main() {
    var j = []byte(`{"name": "Joe","age": "42"}`)
    var j2 = []byte(`{"name": "Joe","age": 42}`)
    stringOrInt(j)
    stringOrInt(j2)
}

func stringOrInt(bytes []byte) {
    var p Person
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if utf8.Valid(p.Age) {
        i, err := strconv.Atoi(string(p.Age))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("got int " + strconv.Itoa(i))
        } else {
            fmt.Println("got string")
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("whoops")
    }
}
```